# Tikz arrowhead size in tree using decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-trees

Tikz is weird when in comes to decorating tree edges.
I'd like to draw a tree with a snakey line with an arrow in the middle.
What sounds simple is somewhat tricky but I found a solution with a further draw action in the `postaction`.
However the default arrowhead size is too small for my liking. Unfortunately tikz seems to ignores the `scale` option when drawing tree edges, the `line width` option however does work but it doesn't achieve what I want.

Here is my code together with an image depicting the problem. The upper arrow from the `\draw` command is how I'd like it to look.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,trees,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    con/.style={draw opacity=0,thick,
                decoration={markings,mark=at position .6 with {\arrow[blue!50!black,draw opacity=1,line width=0.5pt,scale=2]{angle 90}}},
                postaction={decorate},
                postaction={draw=blue!50!black,draw opacity=1,decoration={snake,amplitude=1pt, segment length=8pt},decorate}
               }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw [con] (0,0.3) -- (1.5,0.3);
    \coordinate
        child[grow=east] {
            edge from parent [con]
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The arrow on the tree edge is too small.]

Any idea how to make the lower arrow look like the upper one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably somewhere in the `edge` code the transformations are reset. So you can kindly remind TikZ to scale again either by opening a scope and appyling `scale=x` or using the low-level command `\pgftransformscale`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,trees,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    con/.style={draw=none,
                postaction={decoration={markings,mark=at position .6 with
                      {\pgftransformscale{3}\arrow[blue!50!black]{angle 90}}},decorate},
                postaction={draw,blue!50!black,decoration={snake,amplitude=1pt, 
                      segment length=8pt},decorate}
               }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [con] (0,0.3) -- (1.5,0.3);
    \coordinate
        child[grow=east] {
            edge from parent[con]
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]